# Error5: Access is denied while restarting Event Log service

Tags: windows-7, windows, event-log, windows-services

I am trying to restart windows event log service but i get this error

```
Windows could not stop the windows event log service on local computer.  
Error5: Access is deined
```

My OS is Windows 7 (64) and user type is administrator, and I run service as administrator too.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error you got while restarting  windows event log,

Task scheduler  is associate with the windows event log.To restart the windows event log you need to stop the  task scheduler.

Task Scheduler cant be stopped from windows 2008 so there are some steps to disable  the task scheduler for while

For registry entry to disable

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Schedule

and then in the right side there would be start, change its value from 2 to 4

and then you need to  restart the  machine.once it is booted.you can restart the windows event log.

Once done you can re-enable the task schedule by modifying the entries in the registry as 4 and then restart the machine.

Note :Restart is must after changing the registry entries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make backup up of this folder "c:\windows\system32\winevt".
Check the permissions of this folder, it have to contain full-control for users "eventlog","LOCAL SERVICE" and "LOCAL NETWORK".

After all permission are ok, clear the files in folders and subfolders of winevt.

Reboot system.
Check if service is up or try to start it.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to have corrupted/wrong permissions for files under `C:\windows\system32\winevt\Logs`, in which case removing all the files under that folder fixes the problem.

PS: If it doesn't fix the problem for you, run the Process Monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and look for the string "ACCESS DENIED" after reproducing the problem.