# Windows could not start the Windows Event Log service on local computer. Error 5: Access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, event-log, windows-services

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, I couldn't start the "Windows Event Log Service", which is stopped. I got the following error:

"Windows could not start the windows event log service on local computer.   Error 5: Access is denied"

Let me explain what I have already tried till now:

1. Attempted to start the service manually:

   Go to Services, from Server Configuration > windows event log >right clicked > Start Service
2. Attempted to start the service via a Registry hack:

   Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Schedule" and then in the right side there would be "Start". Change its value from 2 to 4 and restart the machine.
3. Adjusted NTFS permissions for service access:

   1. Open an Explorer window,
   2. Type the following:

      %SystemRoot%\System32\winevt\

      Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key, and you should be directed to the Windows Event Folder. If not, manually navigate to the folder location.
   3. Right-click on the Logs folder and choose Properties.
   4. Click Add.
   5. Under Enter the objects name to select, type NT Service\eventlog.
   6. Click Check Names. Name should be found. If you get a prompt about Name not found, check to see if eventlog is already listed under Group or user names.
   7. Click OK.
   8. Make sure it has Full Control by clicking Full Control.
   9. Click Apply and Ok.
   10. Restart the Computer.

I tried all things which is mentioned above. But none of does not worked for me. Is there anyone can help with my problem?

Comment: You're question is a little unclear.  You're saying the error says "can't STOP the service", yet you say you're trying to START it?  "tried many things that found on googling"  This doesn't tell us anything, to avoid us just suggesting things you've already tried, please edit your question and include exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error5: Access is denied while restarting Event Log service](http://superuser.com/questions/842651/error5-access-is-denied-restarting-a-service-in-windows)

Comment: i saw this question. same but solution did not worked for me

Comment: Please clarify: Are you trying to START it (because it's not currently running) or REstart it?  Like I said, please edit your question to include exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were, otherwise I see no difference in the *question* (whether the existing answer(s) work for you or not).  If you're trying to do this to solve another problem, consider making you question about that actual problem, instead of your supposed solution.

Comment: İ think, the question is very clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I erased all content in Logs folder (C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs). 
Then restarted server. It worked.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. i had the same problem . Apparently i messed up the administrator users right so i didnt have full permission on the logon folder. i copied the items in the logs folder and deleted it and then created a new logs folder and paste the items again and voila it worked. try it.

thanks to I erased all content in Logs folder (C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs). Then restarted server. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by renaming the logs files Security, application, setup and system and then try starting the eventviewer service.
This problem basically start due to these file curruption.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).