# Event Viewer stopped updating

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 Pro 21H2.

I go to Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Diagnostics-Performance > Operational.

There were no events of any kind listed since 11-24-2022.

On 12-17-2022 I clicked “Refresh”, and an Event ID 100 (Boot Duration) was added & was dated 12-17-2022. However the “Shutdown”, Event ID 200 that went with it does not appear.

Under “Operational” I increased the maximum log size to over 20k & this added one ID 100 & one ID 200 to the list. Rebooting did not add any more. Changing the size back to the default 1028 did not affect the list and neither did increasing it again.

I went into Services & did a Windows Event Log Restart & got an error 1051. I looked at the services listed & tried to stop them & got an error 1061.

I went back & tried to do a Windows Event Log Restart again & now get an error 1061.
“Windows could not stop the Windows Event Log service on Local Computer.”
“Error 1061: the service cannot accept control messages at this time.”

However at least some other Sources are getting event updates, such as
Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Powershell > Operational.

Why did Diagnostics-Performance > Operational stop getting updates?

I found this old thread about restarting Event Viewer.
[Error5: Access is denied while restarting Event Log service](https://superuser.com/questions/842651/error5-access-is-denied-while-restarting-event-log-service)

Is there a registry setting that I should try changing?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Start with DISM and SFC.    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
  ....  If that does not work then a Windows 10 Repair will be in order.

Comment: BTW, if you want to try a third-party viewer, which flattens the multiple logs and has search capability, look at Nirsofts's free FullEventLogView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html, I find it makes it easier to diagnose issues.

Comment: Did DISM/SFC solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Both DISMs said the operation completed successfully.
Sfc /scannow said it did not find any integrity violations.

I already tried FullEventLogView and it does show Event ID 100 which is Boot Duration, but it doesn’t show what the duration time is. Event Viewer shows the time which I was interested in.

While not a big problem, it would be nice to know what happened. I’m going to do a Windows update next week & will see what happens.